# c# nullable reference type in abstract class where T : notnull gives compiler warning

Tags: c#-8.0, ef-core-5.0

I have some base classes and interfaces:

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T : notnull
{
        T Id { get; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    string ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity, IEntity<T> where T : notnull
{    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual T Id { get; protected set; } 
// Non-nullable property 'Id' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.
    }
```

How can I avoid this warning? Should I change `notnull` in class to `struct` because then the warning disappears?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use C# 8.0 Nullable Reference Types with Entity Framework Core models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171942/how-to-use-c-sharp-8-0-nullable-reference-types-with-entity-framework-core-model)

Comment: No, it is about navigational properties while my problem is how to handle properly inheritance for non-nullable references.

Comment: Resolution is the same (as mentioned in the top answer), declare a nullable backing field and throw if not initialized or forcefully initialize to the default.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is a little bit weird that I can use `default!` but cannot use `null!`.