# .NET 6 nullable properties warnings for EF Core models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using EF Core, and I have this model:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; } // <- CS8618
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

As pointed out in the above code comment, I get an annoying nullable warning. I'm using the Fluent API to annotate my model, and obviously Author is not nullable as AuthorId is not nullable.

I feel that using `User? Author` instead to make the warning go away is incorrect, as the property is obviously not nullable, and it would be a lie, and also a hint to people using my model that it is nullable.

What is the proper way to deal with this situation? Suppress the warning?

Comment: If you create a new Article the Author property will be null, you might set it during initialization but that is optional. Also if you query for it without including the Author it will be null. So there are several of cases of it being null as I see it.

Comment: Make sure to [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) that cover in detail using entity framework with NRTs.

Comment: Did you try to add `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use C# 8.0 Nullable Reference Types with Entity Framework Core models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171942/how-to-use-c-sharp-8-0-nullable-reference-types-with-entity-framework-core-model)

Answer (score 10):

Since **C#11** (**.NET 7.0**) you can add a `required` modifier.

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required User Author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

And with the `required` modifier, you won't be able to use `var article= new Article();` to create an object instance. So it's great protection for the not nullable property `User`.

Now to create an object instance you **must** do something like:

```
var article= new Article()
{
   User = new();
};
```

Originally answer was posted on:
[What is best way to create .NET6 class with many non-nullable properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71839154/what-is-best-way-to-create-net6-class-with-many-non-nullable-properties)

More detailed info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required

Answer (score 9):

You'd find a lot of different answers [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505347/non-nullable-property-must-contain-a-non-null-value-when-exiting-constructor-co)

But in this particular case, I would ask myself the question: who generates instances of this class?

## 1a

If you are 100% relying on EF Core to generate instances of this class for you by querying the database, and you are 100% sure that you **ALWAYS** use the proper `Include()`, I would safely set the `Author` field to `null!`, which means it assigns the default value `null` on construction and automatically suppresses the nullability error.

```cs
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; } = null!;
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

## 1b

You could also use the above solution with a private constructor to protect that no-one else but EF Core will generate instances of this class.

```cs
public class Article
{
    private Article()
    {
        Author = null!;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

## 2

If you generate instances of this class in any other parts of your code, you would need a constructor to ensure that `Author` is never null after construction.

```cs
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        Author = new User();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

## 3

If you do not allow a default `User` object, it would make sense to expect a `null` value for `Author` but mark it `Required` to ensure that it will never be `null` when written to database.

```cs
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User? Author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

## 4

Use the new [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) keyword to enforce setting the property on construction. It does not solve the issue with the foreign key being out of sync with the object however. Setting both to `required` makes construction complicated, but might be necessary if you sometimes create and save entities to the database linking to other entities using just the foreign key without the full object loaded. EF Core does not like both to be set though, in those cases either property needs to be set to `null!` or `default` on construction depending on use case.

```cs
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required User Author { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not me that downvoted :-) Anyways, I ended up with just disabling the null checking feature. Haven't had a NullReferenceException since 1995 or thereabouts, so not really an issue. They just added that stupid feature to be equally cool as Kotlin.

Comment: @HelloWorld you could still get NRE, usage of NRT is just a compile time feature. But I really appreciate the opportunity of explicitly explaining my **intent** with my code by properly flagging possible null or not-null. It is definitely worth it in the long run when the code base grows.

Comment: EF Core also detects and uses constructors with parameters, so you can change the constructor to require a (non-nullable) `User` instance.

Comment: @Ray I wish this was true, but it does not work with navigation references. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors (the note: _EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor_)

Comment: I see, nevermind then.

Answer (score 0):

Common solution for domain entities is: use private default constructor for EF and public parameterized (keyless) one for explicit object creation. And there are two ways:

1. Mark props with reference type by "promises" (`= null!;`)
2. Disable [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#nonnullable-reference-not-initialized) on EF-constructor:

```
public class MyEntity {
    public int Id { get; [UsedImplicitly] private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public MyEntity(string name) {
        Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)
            ? name
            : throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));
    }

#pragma warning disable CS8618
    [UsedImplicitly]
    private MyEntity(){} // For EF only, allows to fill an object via setters
#pragma warning restore CS8618
}
```

Second approach is much better because checking still works with parameterized constructor. Private constructor makes minimal impact for type safety and doesn't require manual support.

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible Author to be null make the User property nullable:

```
public User? Author { get; set; }
```

If not do this :

```
 public User Author { get; set; } = default!;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put "#nullable disable" above the namespace.

Comment: Disabling null safety for all fields without justification is a bad practice.

Comment: @joakimriedel: If you use database first, then there is no problem, because the database defines the nullability.

Comment: @PoulBak not related. You would still get null if you forget to include the navigation reference in a query, and users of this _code contract_ would get confused.